# swift set crash in asynchous queue

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, set, dispatch-async

I found the weird crash when using `Set` in async queue closure below, confirmed that it only happens in async queue, but `Array` works.

```
func testA1() {
    var set = Set<Int>()

    for i in 0...10 {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            set.update(with: i) // Crash here: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
            // set.insert(i)
        }
    }

    print(set as Any)
}

func testA2() {
    var set = Set<Int>()

    for i in 0...10 {
        DispatchQueue.global().sync {
            set.update(with: i) // Works!
        }
    }

    print(set as Any)
}

func testB() {
    var array = [Int]() // Works!

    for i in 0...10 {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            array.append(i)
        }
    }

    print(array as Any)
}
```

Swift version:

```
Apple Swift version 5.3.2 (swiftlang-1200.0.45 clang-1200.0.32.28)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
```

My bad or swift bug? Why?

Comment: In Swift, both Set and Array are thread-unsafe. Your `Array` case does not work and just crashes in my testing project.

Comment: @OOPer confirmed you're right! Thanks!

Comment: I suggest to run the program with the “Thread Sanitizer” enabled in the diagnostics options.

Comment: Unfortunately, thread unsafe thing may cause every sort of unexpected result. Try adding  `print(i, array)` after the line `array.append(i)` and check if you always get the right result.

Comment: `testB` function crashed for me, too, after changing the loop times to 1000. @OOPer

Comment: Sometimes crash, sometimes generates wrong result, and unfortunately sometimes does not crash and seemingly generates the right result -- hard to debug threading issues.

Comment: you should:
print(set.update(with: i))
It will print error.

Answer (score 0):

Most of datatypes in Swift aren't thread-safe.
You should interact using different ways.

```
protocol ThreadSafeExecutor {
    var semaphore: DispatchSemaphore { get set }
    func wait()
    func signal()
}

extension ThreadSafeExecutor {
    func wait() {
        semaphore.wait()
    }
    func signal() {
        semaphore.signal()
    }
}


class YourClass: ThreadSafeExecutor { 
func someMethod() {
        wait()
        defer {
            signal()
        }
        /// thread-safe code
    }
}
```